# Browserify cannot find installed module sha3

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify, sha-3

I am working on `ethereumjs-lib`package installed from npm which has a dependency on `sha3` module. However browserify is not able to pick it up from the dependencies. I installed `sha3` manually and wrote the simple code shown below, still browserify shows me the error `Cannot find module 'sha3'`
    var unique = require('uniq');
    var sha = require('sha3');

```
var data =[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6];

var uniqueArray = unique(data);

for(var i = 0; i < uniqueArray.length ; i++){
    console.log(uniqueArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue - using ubuntu, latest install of ethereumjs-vm via npm.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve it? I'm also having this issue.